# How should I handle data type differences in testing Express API functions designed for real database types when using mock data?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a straightforward Express API structure:

```
src/
  utils/
    index.ts
    types.ts
  database/
    types.ts
  app.ts
test/
  utils
    unit.test.ts
```

I require the testing of certain functions in src/utils/index.ts using particular mock data.

```
  type mockPlayerDataType = {
    id: number;
    country: {
      code: string;
    };
    data: {
      last: number[];
      weight: number;
      height: number;
    };
  }[];

const mockPlayerData : mockPlayerDataType = [
  {
    id: 1,
    country: { code: 'USA' },
    data: { last: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], weight: 80000, height: 188 },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: { code: 'SRB' },
    data: { last: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], weight: 74000, height: 185 },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    country: { code: 'SUI' },
    data: { last: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], weight: 81000, height: 183 },
  },
];
```

My concern lies in the fact that the functions within src/utils/index.t work with real databases types

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const DataSchema = z.object({
  rank: z.number(),
  points: z.number(),
  weight: z.number(),
  height: z.number(),
  age: z.number(),
  last: z.array(z.number()),
});

export const PlayerSchema = z.object({
  id: z.number(),
  firstname: z.string(),
  lastname: z.string(),
  sex: z.union([z.literal('M'), z.literal('F')]),
  picture: z.string().url(),
  data: DataSchema,
});

export const PlayerListSchema = z.object({
  players: z.array(PlayerSchema),
});

export type PlayerType = z.infer<typeof PlayerSchema>;
export type PlayerListType = z.infer<typeof PlayerListSchema>;
```

What are the recommended best practices in this scenario? Should I modify the function types by creating a new type that can omit specific properties to accommodate the mock data?

I'm concerned that this might be a workaround rather than a well-designed solution, as I'd prefer not to update production functions with test-specific types that won't be used in the production environment.